# upper/lower values of mtry in Simulated annealing algorithm

Tags: r, grid-search, hyperparameters, simulated-annealing

I got this code from web. It uses Grid search and Simulated annealing to tune the parameters of R.Forest. My doubt here is where in the code, the Simulated annealing algorithm finds the starting and ending values of the mtry parameter. I mean usually, we give lower and upper values for these type of algorithms but I could not found any. The result gives me the value MAE and the optimal value of mtry. I am surprised from where it calculates this? I use library(randomForest)

```
d=readARFF("Results.arff")
index <- createDataPartition(log10(d$Result), p = .70,list = FALSE)
tr <- d[index, ]
ts <- d[-index, ] 

index_2 <- createFolds(tr$Result, returnTrain = TRUE, list = TRUE)
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv", index = index_2, search="grid")

grid_search <- train(log10(Effort) ~ ., data = tr,
                     method = "rf",
                     ## Will create 48 parameter combinations
                     tuneLength = 8,
                     metric = "MAE",
                     preProc = c("center", "scale", "zv"),
                     trControl = ctrl)
getTrainPerf(grid_search)

obj <- function(param, maximize = FALSE) {
  mod <- train(log10(Effort) ~ ., data = tr,
               method = "rf",
               preProc = c("center", "scale", "zv"),
               metric = "MAE",
               trControl = ctrl,
               tuneGrid = data.frame(mtry = 10^(param[1])))##, sigma = 10^(param[2])))
  if(maximize)
    -getTrainPerf(mod)[, "TrainMAE"] else
      getTrainPerf(mod)[, "TrainMAE"]
}
num_mods <- 10

## Simulated annealing from base R
set.seed(45642)
tic()
san_res <- optim(par = c(0), fn = obj, method = "SANN",
                 control = list(maxit = num_mods))
san_res
```

Comment: "I got this code from web" -- if you have a question about the logic of a program, the author of that program is the natural person to ask. I'd rather not guess at the reasons that a programmer wrote code they way that they wrote it.

Comment: @JohnColeman, I would definitely ask him but there is no way to contact him. I understand the code but just have a small doubt about the upper/lower value it got from.

Comment: Yes John Coleman, more or less I have the same question.

Comment: `?optim` in the R console gives information about `method = "SANN"` -- including a citation of a source that gives the version of simulated annealing that it is using.

Comment: Thanks John Coleman, I read this but unfortunately, I still have confusion.   I mean how the algorithm will interpret this : tuneGrid = data.frame(mtry = 10^(param[1]). What would be the value of param[1].

Comment: @JohnColeman, can I do in Train of Objective function like this: tuneGrid=expand.grid(mtry=1:20) and then call the objective function from the Simulated annealing?